# Solaris Encrypt command error

Tags: unix, encryption, solaris

I am trying to use the encrypt/decrypt command on solaris

```
 /usr/bin/encrypt -l | -a algorithm [-v]  [-k  key_file]  [-i
 input_file] [-o output_file]

 /usr/bin/decrypt -l | -a algorithm [-v]  [-k  key_file]  [-i
 input_file] [-o output_file]
```

but i am prompted for a key. so i use the -k option and specify the key in a file. But in that case it gives me an error. any idea where i am going wrong?

```
 $ encrypt -a aes -k key.txt -i res.txt -o out.txt
 **encrypt: failed to generate a key: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID**
```

File contents:

```
 $ cat res.txt
 8787878787878787
 $ cat key.txt
 111000110010100100100011001011101010011011010000110101110011000
```

Comment: This may help you : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-3321/scftask-4/index.html

Comment: Thank you fedorqui, but i referred to that document before trying that out. I am afraid it hasnt helped me much in terms of "waht the key should be" it only says towards the end that the message CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID indicates an invalid key, which is why i am here seeking assistance.

Comment: Yes, the error message sums it up -- this key is *invalid*.  Check the key length.  Your best bet is to regenerate the key.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am missing something here. When you say "generate" I have no clue, I opened a file and typed that in. Is there a way to generate the AES key ? I have never gone into Cryptography before so maybe i should read about key lengths. But any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is, indeed, *invalid* as reported in the error message.

You need to regenerate the key.  You can generate the key using `dd` or `pktool`.  An example would be:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/path/to/aes.key bs=16 count=1
```

Refer to [How to Generate a Symmetric Key by Using the dd Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/scftask-10/index.html) and [How to Generate a Symmetric Key by Using the pktool Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/kmf-20/index.html) for more.

Comment: awesome! it worked!! no errors! thank you Devnull!

Comment: just curious to understand what that syntax means, while i read about it, i was trying to set the if to something else than /dev/urandom. I have text "blake" in a file. can i use that??

Comment: If you could use `I have text "blake" in a file`, chances are that you wouldn't have run into this problem with your original key.

Comment: so i can only use urandom if i understand you correctly. right?

Comment: `urandom` isn't a command, it's a device ([man urandom](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom)).  You can use either `dd` or `pktool` as mentioned above.

Comment: yes i know its a device. Thank you devnull. appreciate the help !